# Error when running flux check - no controllers found in the 'flux-system' namespace with the label selector 'app.kubernetes.io/part-of=flux'

Tags: fluxcd

Running on k3s cluster.

I received the following error when trying to run flux check;

```
❯ flux check
► checking prerequisites
✔ Kubernetes 1.25.7+k3s1 >=1.20.6-0
► checking controllers
✗ no controllers found in the 'flux-system' namespace with the label selector 'app.kubernetes.io/part-of=flux'
► checking crds
✗ no crds found with the label selector 'app.kubernetes.io/part-of=flux'
✗ check failed
```